# Is there a way to count time spent on `waiting for query cache` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-optimization

As part of optimization, I'm trying to determine how much time is spent during `waiting for query cache` step. Is it possible to get such an aggregated value?

Comment: you can measure that time via mysql profile. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html